# Getting data from multiple tables into single row while

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to retrieve data from 2 tables and combine multiple rows into a single while loop

posts

```
post_id content          
------  -------      
   1    content1                     
   2    content2           
   3    content3  
   4    content4


comments

id      post_id   content   
------  ------    ------              
   1      1        Wharton university           
   1      2        Yale University
```

sql code I write

```
    mysqli_query( $connect, "SELECT * FROM `posts`
 INNER JOIN  comments ON posts.post_id =  comments.post_id  ORDER BY 1 DESC");
```

The problem  I'm only getting  post id 1  and 2. while there are over 30 posts

I want to get all posts  and comments for each post in a single while loop.

How can I do it ?

Comment: what is jquery's role in this question?

Comment: is to get all columns data from both tables! , do I have to name each column ?

Comment: `there are over 30 posts`, and how many comments? For your case, IMO you should use `left outer join` instead of `inner join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your join to a `LEFT` join instead of an `INNER` join.

The difference being that a `LEFT` join will use `null` when there's no comments, where as `INNER` will only give you the rows that have comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your `INNER` join is taking the union of both tables on the post_id field. You need a `LEFT` join instead of an `INNER` join. The `LEFT` join will give you all the results from the first table.

Comment: Actually, when I started my post, there were no posts. I don't really think I need to copy an extremely elementary SQL concept. Don't get so defensive.